# Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2): while uploading image in Rails 3.1.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I tried to upload an image, I am getting the below error in the log:

> [paperclip] Saving attachments. [paperclip] saving
>   report_photos/original/2.jpg    (0.4ms)  rollback transaction
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 948ms
>
> Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2):
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in
>   `initialize'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`
>   open'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in
>   `block in connect'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in`
>   timeout'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in
>   `timeout'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`
>   connect'
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in
>   `do_start'
>
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:751:in`
>   start'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/net/http/connection_pool/session.rb:84:in `for'
>
>   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/net/http/connection_pool.rb:190:in`
>   session_for'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/net/http/connection_pool.rb:127:in `request'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/net/http/connection_pool/connection.rb:116:in`
>   request'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/http/net_http_handler.rb:44:in `handle'
>
>   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:220:in`block in
>   make_sync_request'   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:234:in
>   `retry_server_errors'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:215:in`make_sync_request'
>   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:390:in `block (2 levels) in
>   client_request'   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:287:in`
>   log_client_request'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:363:in `block in client_request' 
>   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:275:in`return_or_raise'
>   (gem) aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/core/client.rb:362:in `client_request'
>
>   (eval):3:in`put_object'   (gem)
>   aws-sdk-1.3.9/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb:315:in `write'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:295:in`block in
>   flush_writes'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:281:in `each'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:281:in`flush_writes'
>   (gem) paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:214:in `save'
>
>   (gem) paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip.rb:472:in`block in
>   save_attached_files'   (gem) paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip.rb:465:in
>   `block in each_attachment'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip.rb:464:in`each'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip.rb:464:in `each_attachment'   (gem)
>   paperclip-2.8.0/lib/paperclip.rb:471:in`save_attached_files'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in
>   `_run__816062881__save__1024312303__callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_save_callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in
>   `create_or_update'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in`save'
>   (gem) activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in
>   `save'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in`
>   save'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2
>   levels) in save'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in`block in
>   with_transaction_returning_status'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in
>   `transaction'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in`
>   transaction'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in
>   `with_transaction_returning_status'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in`block in
>   save'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in
>   `rollback_active_record_state!'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in`save'
>   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:56:in `block in form_upload'
>
>   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:55:in`each'
>   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:55:in `form_upload'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in`
>   _run__786939238__process_action__16233013__callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`
>   _run_process_action_callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`
>   block in process_action'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block
>   in instrument'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in
>   `instrument'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
>
>   (gem) actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`
>   process'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
>
>   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`
>   dispatch'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in
>   action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in
>   `dispatch'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in`
>   call'   (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in
>   call'   (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'   (gem)
>   journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in`call'
>   (gem) meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   better_errors-0.3.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:51:in `app_call'
>
>   (gem) better_errors-0.3.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:45:in`call'
>   (gem) airbrake-3.1.7/lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
>
>   (gem) sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in`call'   (gem)
>   warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'   (gem)
>   warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'   (gem)
>   warden-1.0.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'   (gem)
>   client_side_validations-3.0.12/lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:17:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'   (gem)
>   rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call' 
>   (gem) remotipart-1.0.2/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
>
>   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in
>   `call'   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in`
>   context'   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
>
>   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in
>   `block in call'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   _run__573045024__call__1024312303__callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`
>   _run_call_callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   rails-dev-tweaks-0.6.1/lib/rails_dev_tweaks/granular_autoload/middleware.rb:34:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`
>   call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`
>   call'   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in
>   `call_app'   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`
>   block in call'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in
>   `tagged'   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call'
>   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in
>   `call'   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
>   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`
>   call'   (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in`
>   call'   (gem) airbrake-3.1.7/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in
>   `_call'   (gem) airbrake-3.1.7/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in`
>   call'   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
>
>   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call'   (gem)
>   rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'   (gem)
>   railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in`catch'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in`process'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'   (gem)
>   eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`run_machine'   (gem)
>   eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in`start'   (gem)
>   thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'   (gem)
>   rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in`run'   (gem)
>   rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'   (gem)
>   railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start'   (gem)
>   railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top
>   (required)>'   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
>   (gem) railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
>
>   script/rails:6:in`require'   script/rails:6:in `'
>
> Started POST "/__better_errors/98360080/variables" for xxx-xxx-xx-xx(ip address)

This is an maintenance project and I am using rvm with Ruby 1.9.3p551 and Rails Rails 3.2.13 and paperclip used for uploads.
Please suggest where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1 . I think when you clone the original project after that you do bundle install or bundle update in that phase you update the version of your gem in Gemfile/Gemfile.Lock and change some dependent method.

2 . Check with paperclip gem dependency with there associated gem.

3 . Also check is you AWS connection is proper with respective S3 bucket